# Getting list of all vendors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app

I am doing the following to take the vendor out of the products and using unique to get it to the front end to list each vendor on a store.

**Controller:**

```
@count = ShopifyAPI::Product.count
@n = 1
@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, limit: 250, page: @n)
if (@count > 50) && params[:page_number]
  @page_number = params[:page_number].to_i
  @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: {page: @page_number})
end
```

**front end:**

```
<% @products.map(&:vendor).uniq.each do |vendor| %>
...
...
<% end %>

<% if (@count > 50) && (@page_number.present? && @page_number > 1) %>
  <%= link_to "<", company_shop_vendors_path(shop_id: @shop.id, page_number: (@page_number - 1)) %> <%= link_to "1", company_shop_vendors_path(shop_id: @shop.id, page_number: 1) %> <%= link_to "#{@page_number + 1} >", company_shop_vendors_path(shop_id: @shop.id, page_number: (@page_number + 1)) %>
<% elsif (@count > 50) %>
  <%= link_to "#{@n+1} >", company_shop_vendors_path(shop_id: @shop.id, page_number: (@n += 1)) %>
<% end %>
```

This gets me the vendors but not how i would like.

The whole page system is a terrible attempt and I actually use a search form also which is better.  paginating through the product pages just gets me the unique vendors on each page and when there are hundreds of pages, it's pointless.

What is the best way to do this?

Is there maybe a way to paginate and throw all of the vendors into memory and THEN display to the front end all of the vendors uniquely?

Aisde from that, the only other option is to store the vendors in the database on a Product API request and then Product create webhook --- instead of using the API directly.

What do you think?

Comment: What about using an expiring cache?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.  Looked into it and looks to be on the right path.  I don't have enough experience atm with caching to do that.  I ended up just putting a form to call the api request, paginate through products, get vendors listed uniquely and save them to the db if they don't already exist.

Comment: This seems to be what other similar apps do and will be better than calling the API every time i want to list vendors.  I however did find one person who claims they were able to get only vendors (even tho Shopify doesn't support this) through node --- but everyone else said it wasn't possible apparently.

Answer (score 3):

Creepy Way but might help someone who doesn't want to loop through products and won't able to do through app proxy

1. Ask Merchant to visit below URL on their store

> https://{{ shop_doamin }}/admin/products/vendors.json

This will list all product vendors in JSON format.

2. Ask them to put this JSON in textbox save this JSON on your local DB and serve from there.

Might break the automate process. but can be helpful when you don't want to loop through large data.

Hope the information will make sense and might help.

---

UPDATE : IT's now possible with APIs only below is it's graphQL query

```
$query = '{ shop { productVendors(first:100){ edges { node } } } }';
```

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: @Stanley thank's for pointing that, Now vendor list can be fetch using query only. I have updated that

Answer (score 1):

You know Shopify has a Liquid construct where they will show you all the vendors of a shop?

https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/shop#shop-vendors

So you can easily use that to send your App that listing, using an App Proxy. Is a heck of a lot more efficient than iterating products, and other hocus pocus.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the API to display vendors --- and I am sure there is a way to do this while keeping the results in memory --- I cycle through the products and product pages and store the vendors in my database and display it that way.  I allow users to "Sync" their vendors if they add new ones.  I did not implement webhooks just in case someone makes a product with a new vendor that is mispelled or something.